# generating and storing random arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, random

I am working on a program which takes the initial array as an input and then randomly generates 10 random arrays from the initial array.

I have written a function to generate a single random array from the initial array.

However,I am unable to develop a code which calls this function in the main function and generates 10 such random arrays.I will also be using these 10 randomly generated arrays for further calculation in the main function.

Since my knowledge of C++ is limited for now,I am not aware of using vectors for dynamic allocation.It would be of great help if anyone can guide be regarding the code to be used in the main function.

Here `int initial[]` is the first array used to generate 10 other random arrays using the `int *newparents()` function. When the `newparents()` function is called in main it returns one randomly shuffled array.

I would request your help in generating 10 random arrays in the main function by calling the `newparents()` function and then storing them for further use.

Code :

```
int initial[] =
{ 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200 };
int size = sizeof(initial) / sizeof(initial[0]);

int *newparents()
{
    int *pt = new int[size];
    random_shuffle(&initial[0], &initial[size]);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        pt[i] = initial[i];
    }
    return pt;
}

int main()
{
    int *p;
    p = newparents();
    cout << "p1=" << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout << *(p + i) << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why not just create an array of arrays and call newparents() in a loop to fill it?

Comment: 1. Try to make the question more readable.

2. Consider using `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: 3. avoid new where you can - use containers/smart pointers

Comment: Please indent your code. This is not readable.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this using `std::vector` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector< std::vector<int> >
GenerateRandomArrays( std::vector<int> const & inInitialArray, int inNumberOfArrays)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > generatedArrays;
    std::vector<int> tempArray(inInitialArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < inNumberOfArrays; i++)
    {
        std::random_shuffle(tempArray.begin(), tempArray.end());
        generatedArrays.push_back(tempArray);
    }
    return generatedArrays;
}

int main() {
    // Creates the initial array.
    std::vector<int> initial{ 10,20,30,40,50 };
    auto blah = GenerateRandomArrays(initial, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
50  20  40  30  10
50  40  30  10  20
20  10  30  50  40
30  40  20  10  50
30  50  20  10  40
20  50  10  40  30
50  30  20  10  40
30  40  20  10  50
20  10  50  40  30
20  50  10  40  30
```

**Note :** I am creating a new `tempArray` only because I think you do not want to alter the `intial` vector. If that is not a case for you then, you can just shuffle the `initial` array itself and add it to the vector of vectors.

Comment: I get the following errors while compiling this code.Thank your help.error: in C++98 'initial' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'||error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' || error: 'blah' does not name a type|

Comment: Which compiler are you using ? Such initialization are only supported using C++ 11 or above. Kindly compile using C++11.

Comment: Just take `inInitialArray` by value, then you can avoid the need for `tempArray`

Comment: @Caleth : Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

To create array of 10 pointers to the shuffled arrays using your code you can simply:

```
int *arr[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    arr[i] = newparents();
```

`int *arr[10];` will create array of 10 pointers to `int`, which is what what your `newparents();` function returns, a pointer to the first `int` of shuffled array.

Since you allocated those arrays on the heap, make sure you free that memory once finished with them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    delete[] arr[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have written a function to generate a single random array from the initial array.

No, you wrote a function to shuffle the initial array in place and then copy it. This is frankly a bit odd, because I don't see why you want to mutate the global in-place (after the first time you call your function, the global array is still called "initial" but is no longer in its initial state).

> Since my knowledge of C++ is limited for now,I am not aware of using vectors for dynamic allocation.

The whole point is that `std::vector` handles all the allocation for you, avoiding the memory leaks and manual copying in your current code.

If you take the time to use C++ properly, instead of trying to write C in C++, the code is pretty trivial:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

// let's avoid mutating our global state
const std::vector<int> Seeds =
{10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200};

// this shuffles a copy of the argument passed
std::vector<int> shuffle(std::vector<int> v) {
    std::random_shuffle(begin(v), end(v));
    return v;
}

// return n independently-shuffled copies of "initial"
std::vector<std::vector<int>> shuffle_n(size_t n,
                                        std::vector<int> const& initial) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> result(n);
    std::generate_n(begin(result), n,
                    [&initial]() {
                        return shuffle(initial);
                    });
    return result;
}

int main() {
    // one line to create 10 shuffled vectors
    auto allparents = shuffle_n(10, Seeds);

    // and one loop to print them all
    for (auto &v : allparents) {
        std::cout << '{';
        std::copy(begin(v), end(v),
                  std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << "}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response,but i get the following error. error: cannot convert 'const std::vector<int>' to 'size_t {aka unsigned int}' for argument '1' to 'std::vector<std::vector<int> > shuffle_n(size_t, const std::vector<int>&)'|
|error: unable to deduce 'auto&&' from 'allparents'|error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope|error: 'end' was not declared in this scope|.I know these errors are trivial,but your help is greatly appreciated as i am still learning the language through some examples such as these.

Comment: You must be using a pretty elderly compiler then, but you still haven't said what it is. This compiles fine with C++11 which is 7 years old now - if you want more help you need to tell us your platform, compiler and version.

Comment: I am using code::blocks 17.12 on windows and the default compiler selected is GNU GCC compiler with compiler flag setting "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO c++ language standard[-std=c++11].Any changes to be made here? Thanks

Comment: Oh, my mistake: I introduced a bug prettifying the code. For reference, if you have an error, it usually shows the line where it occurs, and it's taken me several reads of your un-formatted comment to figure out what it told you for free. Take a look at my edit, and think about how you could have read the error to figure this out for yourself.

Comment: Thank a lot.The code works perfect now.Can you tell me,how do i call the individual elements of the 10 arrays generated for further use in my code

Comment: `allparents[0]`..`allparents[9]`, same as indexing any other vector or array. You might be at the stage where you'd benefit from getting a good C++ book ...

Comment: Yeah sure,Would you suggest any good book available as pdf online?

Comment: The 10 vectors generated in the above code are completely random.Is it possible to modify the above code in a manner that a new vector is generated by swapping any 2 random elements of the initial vector.I tried using srand() and generated 2 random index values,and then swapped these indices in the initial vector to generate a new vector.However,I am not able to generate multiple random vectors in this manner and then store in the 2d vector allparents.Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should probably ask a distinct question - it doesn't cost anything!